# How to load large geojson file into mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mbtiles, vector-tiles, tippecanoe

I have a large geoJson file (almost 700MB) and I need to load it in my map using mapbox and openmaptiles server.
I need to have an external file, so I can't use Mapbox Studio for uploading and converting the data.

I can't use [geojson2mvt](https://github.com/NYCPlanning/labs-geojson2mvt) since the file is large and it exceeds the memory heap. So, I used Tippecanoe to convert it to .Mbtiles. However, I can't use this format in mapbox.
I follow these steps in order to convert Mbtiles to .mvt:

1. Install tippecanoe (https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) and
   generate mbtiles:

   `tippecanoe -o mbt_file.mbtiles -z18 input_file.geojson -pC`
2. Install mb-util(https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) and convert
   mbtiles to mvt tiles:

   `./mbutil/mb-util mbt_file.mbtiles mvt_dir --image_format=pbf`
3. All files are now in proper format, but you have to change their
   extension:

   `find mvt_dir -iname "*.pbf" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%\.pbf}.mvt"' {} \;`

the file has been successfully converted to .mvt, but when I try to load it in my map it displays the following error:

```
blob:null/e1d9d487-dfa4-48b1-aa0e-b66527f28ac8:11754 Uncaught Error: Unimplemented type: 3
    at No.skip (blob:null/e1d9d487-dfa4-48b1-aa0e-b66527f28ac8:11754)
    at No.readFields (blob:null/e1d9d487-dfa4-48b1-aa0e-b66527f28ac8:11574)
    at new Za (blob:null/e1d9d487-dfa4-48b1-aa0e-b66527f28ac8:9948)
    at $a (blob:null/e1d9d487-dfa4-48b1-aa0e-b66527f28ac8:9964)
    at No.readFields (blob:null/e1d9d487-dfa4-48b1-aa0e-b66527f28ac8:11573)
    at new VectorTile (blob:null/e1d9d487-dfa4-48b1-aa0e-b66527f28ac8:9978)
    at blob:null/e1d9d487-dfa4-48b1-aa0e-b66527f28ac8:14432
    at XMLHttpRequest.T.r.onload (blob:null/e1d9d487-dfa4-48b1-aa0e-b66527f28ac8:416)
```

Can someone help me fix this? or is there any way to display my large geojson file?

Thanks!

Comment: Related? https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1567

Comment: Just FYI, if you do `-e mvt_dir` instead of `-o mbt_file.mbtiles` in the first step, you won't need the second step.

Answer (score 3):

As @Caramiriel alluded to, Unimplemented type: 3 usually means your tiles are gzipped and Mapbox GL JS is expecting uncompressed tiles. Just add a Content-Encoding: gzip header and let the browser do decompression on the fly.

Comment: how to decompress the file without using the browser? or where I have to add the content encoding?

Comment: To the HTTP response header, or decompress those tiles using gzip command,a if you don't care about performance.

Comment: I've head a similar problem and this answer finally gave me the solution. I've been searching for days and the documentation doesn't mention this small fact. Thanks !